# jQuery remove specific field from dynamically generated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon, I'm hoping someone can help me here.

I'm quite new to `jQuery` so forgive me if this is a really obvious mistake I'm making.

I've got a form which allows me to add additional fields, I have it working and I've got it so they have unique ID tags but I'd like so when I click my `removeFieldTeam` it removes the specific field I have clicked on.

At the moment, it removes fields automatically from the bottom upwards.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sz91dcy/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nice choice of colors for the demo.

Comment: For remove button, each time you are adding the same ID. Hence all remove buttons have same IDs. Change them to classes and remove the closest div

Comment: unfortunately you _don't_ have unique ID tags. Every time you add a new field you duplicate the IDs of the + and - buttons (which, btw, seem to be invisible in your demo, maybe check your CSS). Anyway, you really only need one "+" button, and you can either tie the "minus" buttons to the related  textbox using data-attributes, or you could rely on the HTML structure and look for the textbox relative to the button by traversing the structure using jquery's "find" , "closest" etc. as required.

Comment: Anyway, apart from the tags problem, it's hard to say you've made a _mistake_ as such - your current code just takes a totally different approach, by removing the textbox with the last generated ID. There's no attempt to try and identify the textbox related to the clicked button, so there's no mistake really, you just need to make the button do something else entirely.

Comment: It shows fieldteam1, 2, 3, etc when I view it?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ADyson - I thought it was deleting the div with a certain ID. Can you recommend a better way of doing it?

Comment: @sconner87 https://imgur.com/a/Boc5r doesn't look right to me

Comment: " I thought it was deleting the div with a certain ID" yes it is, but it's always the last one, because you just use the current count. It doesn't attempt to identify the div which relates to the clicked button. Anyway, I suggested above how you might do it in order to achieve your goal. Vinod's answer takes one of those approaches.

Comment: I get you - I've updated that fiddle by the way so you can actually see the text.  The background is blue on mine.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated jquery code. I tested, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            // Set the counter value
            var countTeam = 1;

            $("#addFieldTeam").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                // If there's more than 10 fields, throw an alert
                if (countTeam == 10) {
                    alert("Only 10 fields allowed");
                    return false;
                }
                // Declaring our new div and adding the form input.
                var newField = $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .attr({
                        id: "newFieldTeam" + countTeam,
                        class: "form-group"
                    });

                newField.after().html(
                    '<label class="form-label-bold" for="fieldTeam' + countTeam + '"' + '>' +
                    'Team '+countTeam+'</label>' +
                    '<input class="form-control fullish" id="fieldTeam' + countTeam +
                    '" type="text">' +
                    '<span><a class="minuslinkreport removeFieldTeam" href="#"> - </a></span>'
                );
                // adding the new field to the page within the #fieldGroupTeam div
                newField.appendTo('#fieldGroupTeam');

                // Increase the counter by 1
                countTeam++;
                console.log(countTeam);

            });
            // Once there's no more fields to delete, throw an error.
            $(document).on('click', ".removeFieldTeam", function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (countTeam < 2) {
                    alert("No fields to remove");
                    return false;
                }
                countTeam--
                console.log(countTeam);
                // Decrease the counter by 1 and remove the field.
                console.log($(this).closest('div'));
                 $(this).closest('div').remove();


            });
        });
```

For the remove button, I changed it from id to class, and onclick I am removing the closest div.

Please test and let me know if this works.

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fv6r6j0/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes more sense, I was coming at it with the wrong approach.

Comment: Yup :) Learn Learn all the way